# Why does subtraction using for loops fail in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, subtraction

I'm trying to create a simple calculator program in **Python 3**.
But when I take some numbers to do subtraction, it gives me a weird answer.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

I have a Linux computer, and to run my code, I use repl.it. 
I tried making some code to do a different starting, but it still didn't work.

Code:

```
elif type1=="subtraction":

    try:
      numnum=int(input("How many numbers are you going to need: "))
      for i in range(numnum):
        num1=int(input("Insert a number: "))
        if i==0:
          totalanswer1=num1
        else:  
          totalanswer1=num1-totalanswer1
    except TypeError:
      if num1=="end session" or numnum=="end session":
        break
      else:
        print ("ERROR!!!")
        exit()
    totalanswer1=str(totalanswer1)
    print ("Answer: "+totalanswer1)
```

When I tried 5-5-5, it gave me the answer 5, even though I was trying to -5

Comment: It sounds like you want `totalanswer1 - num1` not `num1 - totalanswer1`

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks a lot for the help